# Is set of isolated points of S closed?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In metric space,  $(X,d)$

I know limit points of some set(S maybe) is closed in X

Then is set of isolated points of S is closed?

Want to make sure if closure of isolated points of S doesn't intersect with limit points of S

But i think i got it and i think i should leave it for people like me

Answer (score 4):

It's not closed in general: take the set $\{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

Comment: You should mention that you have taken $X=\Bbb R$ endowed with the usual or Euclidean metric $d_u.$

Comment: I think Matt Samuel was right. $X$ should be this set with $0$. In that case, $S$ would actually be the set @astrobarrel provided.

Answer (score 3):

Usually an isolated point in a metric space is defined to be a point that is an open set. Therefore any set of isolated points is in fact *open*, but it need not be closed. There was an example already given, and it is almost correct. Let
$$X=\{0\}\cup\{\frac1n|n\in \mathbb Z^+\} $$
Then every point is isolated except for $0$, and the union of all isolated points is open, but it is not closed because a neighborhood of $0$ always contains an isolated point.

Comment: I think you meant to say it is closed (instead of is not).

Comment: @north No, that's the whole point of the answer. I exhibit a space where the set of isolated points is not closed.

Comment: Sorry, I am viewing your set as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ where isolated points are actually defined very differently than what you have posted.  Since $0$ is the only limit point of the set given by @astrobarrel, you made his set closed. I find his example to actually be the correct one.

Comment: @north $0$ is not an isolated point. If you omit it, the set of isolated points is closed because it is the whole space.

Comment: Ah, by set of isolated points, the OP wanted $S$ to be the set of all isolated points in $X$. I interpreted the question as being a subset of $X$ containing only isolated points that is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

In $(R, std metric) $

S={$\frac{1}{n}$ n$\in$N}

S is set of isolated points since $\forall \frac{1}{n}$$ \exists $r= $\frac{1}{n(n+1)} $

But closure of S has 0 as element

So set of isolated points may not be closed